# Variable from function not displaying outside the function

Tags: php

I am having trouble getting the value of a variable which is in a function outside the function...

Example:

```
function myfunction() {
    $name = 'myname';
    echo $name;
}
```

Then I call it...

```
if (something) {
    myfunction();
}
```

This is echoing `$name`, but if I try to echo `$name` inside the input value it won't show:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>"
```

How can I get access to this variable value?

Comment: Did you try to globalize your variable. i.e. define it as global: global $name; $name= 'myname';?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$name` variable is local until you explicitly define it as global:

```
function myfunction() {
    global $name;
    $name = 'myname';
    echo $name;
}
```

But this doesn't seem like a good use of globals here. Did you mean to return the value and assign it? (Or just use it once?)

```
function myfunction() {
    $name = 'myname';
    return $name;
}

...
$name = myfunction();
```

Comment: exactly what i was about to write :-) people forget global is two-way

Answer (score 0):

Read abour [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
The variable has local scope. You have to made it global. But better, use some template engine or implement Registry

Answer (score 0):

Its a matter of scope..

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Just as when you're in a closed room, we cant see what you do, but if you open a door, or put in a video camera people can, or can see limited things, or hear limited things.. this is how stuff works in computers too

Answer (score 0):

You should read the php page about [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

To do what you want there are two solutions:

1. Make `$name` global, or
2. `return` the variable from the function

Answer (score 0):

The `$name` variable is local in that function. So it's accessible only inside that function. If you want it to be accesible everywhere you can do the following:

- declare it outside the function and inside the function type: `global $name;`
- still declare it outside but pass her as a function argument by reference:

  `function myFunc(&$name) {
     $name = "text";
  }`